# jasper reports loading report from jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm loading the jasper reports file from .jasper file to improve the performance as below.

```
JasperReport rpt = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(location);
```

but I have a requirement now, that a query which is formed dynamically has to be set to .jasper (compiled) file. is there a way to do the same?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

Java

```
JasperReport rpt = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(Your .jasper file path);

Map paramMap = new HashMap();
paramMap.put("p_sql", "select * from baztable where foo='bar' and fuga='hoge' order by username");
// pass the dynamic query to .jasper file.
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(rpt, paramMap, connection);
```

jrxml

```
<parameter name="p_sql" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["select * from baztable order by username"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[$P!{p_sql}]]>
</queryString>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $P! (Parameter with exclamation) which can be used for conditional queries.
Using this you can craft dynamic queries based on certain conditions.
A guide for the same can be found [here.](http://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/how-write-conditional-query-ireport-using-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack method for the JRXML file. The JRXML file has your query. You can write a Java code or any other code to replace/write down your Query here:

Sample MongoDB Query:

```
<queryString language="MongoDbQuery">
    {'collectionName':'customer'}
</queryString>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open .jasper file in to ireport so you can load .jasper file and edit it.